# Hide codeigniter folder name when folder is subfolder of another php application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have core php application and codeigniter in subfolder  of this application. i want to hide CI folder name for a single controller . just like

The original url is
`http://example.com/ci/welcome/test`

and the excepted URl is

`http://example.com/welcome/test`

what is the htaccess base solution for this

Comment: using `RewriteRule ^welcome/([a-zA-Z0-9-_']+)$ ci/welcome/$1 [NC,QSA]` using  this rule but it show page of `welcome/index` not `welcom/test `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution

1. in htaccess

`RewriteRule  ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_']+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_']+) ci/$1/$2 [L,NC,QSA]`

2. on index.php last line change `require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';` to `require_once APPPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';`

3 on APPPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php' search $RTR and put this code behind

```
if( $RTR->class =='mainfoldername' ){
            $RTR->class =$RTR->method;
            $RTR->method = $RTR->uri->rsegments[3];
            $total_segment = count( $RTR->uri->segments );
            foreach( $RTR->uri->segments as $k=>$uri  ){
                if( $k != $total_segment ){
                    $RTR->uri->segments[$k] = $RTR->uri->segments[$k+1];
                    $RTR->uri->rsegments[$k] = $RTR->uri->rsegments[$k+1];
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

please use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ci/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: its not working redirect on 404 page of main appliaiton

Comment: please use this   RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^ci/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: I am using this rule `RewriteRule ^welcome/([a-zA-Z0-9-_']+)$ ci/welcome/$1 [L,R=301]` but its show only index function not other function

Answer (score 0):

Try these

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci/$1 [L]